# Variational derivative of Wasserstein distance using Benaumou-Brenier formulation

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-transportation

I learned from the gradient flow theory in Wasserstein space that an equation of gradient flow type

$$\partial_t \rho + \nabla \cdot (\rho \nabla \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho})=0,$$
can be derived as the limit of the Jordan-Kinderlehrer-Otto sheme as

$$\rho^{k} = \min \frac{1}{2}W_2^2(\rho^{k-1},\rho) + \tau F(\rho)$$ 
where $W_2^2(\rho^{k-1},\rho)$ is the Wasserstein-2 distance, see the paper https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036141096303359. 
In their paper, it was shown that as $\tau$ goes to zero the solutions of the sheme converge to the solution of the gradient flow equation. They used the definition of Wasserstein-2 distance via optimal transport, for example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric.

We also know that the Wasserstein-2 distance can also be defined using the Benamou-Brenier formulation as
$$W_2^2(\rho_0,\rho_1):=\bigg\{\inf \int_{0}^1\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho |v|^2 dxdt$$
$$\text{s.t. } \quad \partial_t \rho + \nabla\cdot (\rho v)=0,$$
$$\quad\qquad\qquad \text{and } \rho(0,x)=\rho_0(x),\rho(1,x)=\rho_1(x)\bigg\}$$
I want to know how can we show the JKO sheme converge to the gradient flow equation. That is, how to find the following derivative
$$\frac{d}{d\tau} W_2^2(\rho_0,\rho_\tau)$$
using the Benamou-Brenier definition of Wasserstein distance with $\rho_0$ given?

$$\frac{d}{d\tau} \bigg\{\inf \int_{0}^1\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \rho |v|^2 dxdt$$
$$\text{s.t. } \quad \partial_t \rho + \nabla\cdot (\rho v)=0,$$
$$\quad\qquad\qquad \text{and } \rho(0,x)=\rho_0(x),\rho(1,x)=\rho_\tau(x)\bigg\}$$

Comment: In the JKO scheme you've got to take argmin, whereas in Benamou-Brenier it's only inf rather then arginf! Regarding your question I suggest consulting Santambrogio's book "Optimal transport for Applied Mathematicians" which gives in chapter 8 both, as nice heuristic picture as well as stringent proof.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have read the book you suggested, but the proof therein use the traditional definition of Wasserstein space rather than the Benamou-Brenier definition. I want to use only the Benamou-Brenier definition to show the JKO sheme converges.

Comment: Alternatively, you may find Brenier's notes http://www.math.ens.fr/~brenier/salsa.pdf, in particular ch.2.5 helpful.